# Determining the input voltage range of an adaptor

Tags: power-supply, voltage, voltage-measurement

The label of a power adaptor is damaged so no information if the input voltage is 110V only or 100-240V range.  The output is 500mA at 5.5V.

I would like to use the adaptor in a 220V country.  How can I test/measure the input range of the adaptor and check whether it can be used with 220V?

Comment: Google image search of the same device or reverse engineer the pcb

Comment: Why take the risk? Throw it away and buy another one.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot be sure !
And it might work, for a short time, and fail when you think it's OK.
So indeed the best advise is to throw it away and get a proper 240V rated adapter.
Why risk fire or whatever when a proper adapter is cheap to buy and is guaranteed to work safely ?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Yes to replace the original one is the easiest way but I was wondering if there is a technical method to determine the input voltage as well. Again thanks for all the replies and sorry if it was off-topic..

Comment: There is a technical method in then you would need to reverse-engineer the adapter and look at the ratings of all the componets. That would still not be a 100% guarantee though. And most adapters cannot be safely opened and closed again. Geeting a 240 V rated one is the better option.